# tikz - trapezium node - fix angle and height, adjustable width

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using TikZ, I want to draw trapezium nodes all of which have a fixed height and angle(s), but whose widths vary.  I can't find any combination of parameters that does what I want.  Specifically, with `trapezium stretches=false`, the angle is correct but the widths are ridiculously large.  With `trapezium stretches=true` or `trapezium stretches body=true`, the widths are correct but the angles are all wrong.

A similar problem seems to have been discussed at [Drawing parallelogram with fixed angle, width and height?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106969/drawing-parallelogram-with-fixed-angle-width-and-height), but I don't see an *answer* in there, only talk about why the obvious thing doesn't work, which frankly I don't care, I'm only interested in what to change so that it *does* work.  (One clarification, though: these trapezoidal bars need to be nodes so that they can be addressed in the larger document, for labeling and so on.  Also, I'm setting the size of the node with `\rule` because when I tried to do it exclusively with `minimum width` I got division-by-zero errors.  It appears that a `trapezium` node cannot be empty.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage[active,pdftex,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment[]{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5mm,y=5mm,every node/.style={
  trapezium, trapezium angle=67.5, draw,
  inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
  minimum height=1.81mm, minimum width=0pt
}]
\node [] at (0,9) {\rule{1pt}{0.1pt}};
\node [] at (0,8) {\rule{5pt}{0.1pt}};
\node [] at (0,7) {\rule{10pt}{0.1pt}};
\node [trapezium stretches] at (0,6) {\rule{1pt}{0.1pt}};
\node [trapezium stretches] at (0,5) {\rule{5pt}{0.1pt}};
\node [trapezium stretches] at (0,4) {\rule{10pt}{0.1pt}};
\node [trapezium stretches body] at (0,3) {\rule{1pt}{0.1pt}};
\node [trapezium stretches body] at (0,2) {\rule{5pt}{0.1pt}};
\node [trapezium stretches body] at (0,1) {\rule{10pt}{0.1pt}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which renders as:

[image: rendering of tikz code above, demonstrating problem with width/angle]

Comment: What happens if you use `inner sep=1pt`?

Comment: @MarkWibrow The trapezium is then more likely to be the right width (it still becomes ridiculously wide with very small inner contents) but is too tall.

Comment: Consider the second trapezium in your code. As the `inner sep` is `0pt`, the node contents are `5pt x .1 pt`. This means the total trapezium width is `(5+2*.1*cot(67.5))/.1=50.828` times the height. This factor is used when the trapezium is scaled to some minimum height to make the shape "look the same but bigger" (PGF 2.10 manual p423). The `minimum height` is `1.81mm=5.14993pt`, so the new width is `50.828*5.149=261.713pt (9.199cm)`. This is _technically_ the correct behaviour, but I concede it does produce shapes that would be unanticipated even with a close reading of the manual.

Answer (score 13):

One possibility would be to use `text width` to control the width; using one argument for a new mytrap style, you the can use the style like this:

```
\node [mytrap=<width>] at (<position>) {};
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
%\usepackage[active,pdftex,tightpage]{preview}
%\PreviewEnvironment[]{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5mm,y=5mm,
  mytrap/.style={
  trapezium, trapezium angle=67.5, draw,inner xsep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
  minimum height=1.81mm, text width=#1
}]
\foreach \ancho [count=\xi] in {5,10,...,100}  
  \node [mytrap=\ancho pt] at (0,-\xi) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This appears to work in a toy test.  I need to see if it also works in my larger document (which will involve careful revision to remove the kludge-around I came up with last night) before accepting, though.

Comment: How do I invert it? I mean I want longer side at top and shorter side at bottom.

Answer (score 10):

maybe like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage[active,pdftex,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment[]{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5mm,y=5mm,every node/.style={
  trapezium, trapezium angle=67.5, draw,
  inner ysep=5pt, outer sep=0pt,
  minimum height=1.81mm, minimum width=0pt
}]
\node[inner xsep=6pt] at (0,5){};
\node[inner xsep=5pt] at (0,4){};
\node[inner xsep=4pt] at (0,3){};
\node[inner xsep=3pt] at (2,5){};
\node[inner xsep=2pt] at (2,4){};
\node[inner xsep=1pt] at (2,3){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

see pag. 422 of the TikZ manual 
(there are more chunks of code you could remove, I left them there since I was not sure you actually need them for other purposes)

Comment: This doesn't work in the larger context: specifically, that `minimum height=1.81mm`?  Is meant to be the *fixed* height of the trapezoid, regardless of the width.  also, what were you trying to point me to on page 422 of the TikZ manual? I don't see anything enlightening.

Comment: that was an example, you can set set the ysep to a different value or remove it completely so that the height will be fixed at 1.81mm, and you can still control the width with the inner xsep (also in mm if you wish). I pointed you to the part of the manual where it explains that the node label can be empty, since you thought it cannot.

Comment: I'm aware that the node label is *supposed* to be allowed to be empty, but if I write a trapezium-shaped node with empty contents and zero inner ysep, I get a division-by-zero error.

Comment: the reason why is explained in those pages, that's why I linked them :)

Comment: Would you please just spell out for me what you are trying to communicate?  I have read page 422 several times now and I do not see anywhere it says that `\node [trapezium, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=10pt] {};` is expected to produce a division by zero error.  To the contrary, as far as *I* can tell, it implies that that should work Just Fine.