# Can we use `let` (from `TikZ`) inside a node's style definition?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-calc

I know how to use `let` from `TikZ calc` library into a `path` command and fix some parameter of a particular node on that path. But I would like to use inside node's style definition.

As an example, consider how to automatically fix height and border rotation for a `single arrow` between to nodes:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.arrows, calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (a) {A};
\node[draw, above right=2cm and 1cm of a] (b) {B};
\path (a.north east) let \p1=($(b.south west)-(a.north east)$) in
    node[single arrow, draw, 
        minimum height={veclen(\x1,\y1)}, 
        shape border uses incircle,
        shape border rotate={atan2(\y1,\x1)},
        anchor=tail] at (a.north east) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to define this arrow node with a style similar to `arrow between a and b` and be able to use

```
\node[arrow between a and b] {};
```

The problem is that I've never seen `let` inside a `.\style` for a `node`. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Style args does not permit such a syntax, there is a mandatory = sign. What is not convenient in the answers you had?

Comment: @Tarass We could extend the `/tikz/.unknown` code but that's just messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, with the [`math` library](https://tikz.dev/library-math) and its [`/tikz/evaluate` key](https://tikz.dev/library-math#tikz/evaluate) (not to be confused with [`/pgf/foreach/evaluate`](https://tikz.dev/pgffor#pgf/foreach/evaluate)):

   ```
   \tikzset{
     arrow between/.style args={#1 and #2}{
       evaluate={
         coordinate \diffPoint;
         \diffPoint=(#2.south west)-(#1.north east);},
       shape=single arrow, draw,
       at={(#1.north east)}, anchor=tail,
       shape border uses incircle,
       minimum height=veclen(\diffPoint)*1pt,
       shape border rotate={atan2(\diffPointy,\diffPointx)}}}
   ```
2. Yes, by using the `let … in` parser but deactivating the switching-back to `\path` parsing.

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \tikzset{parse let/.code={\def\tikz@cc@stop@let in{}\tikz@let@command et #1in}}
   \makeatother
   \tikzset{
     arrow between'/.style args={#1 and #2}{
       parse let={\p{diffPoint}=($(#2.south west)-(#1.north east)$)},
       shape=single arrow, draw,
       at={(#1.north east)}, anchor=tail,
       shape border uses incircle,
       minimum height=veclen(\p{diffPoint})*1pt,
       shape border rotate={atan2(\y{diffPoint},\x{diffPoint})}}}
   ```
3. Or just using the calculations on the PGF level

   - where `\pgfkeyssetevalue{<key>}{<value>}` is the faster version of `\pgfkeys{<key>/.expanded=<value>}`,
   - where `\pgfmathveclen@` is the faster version of `\pgfmathveclen` or `\pgfmathparse{veclen(…)` since the parameters don't need to get parsed again and
   - where we're re-using the globalized dimensions `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y` from `\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints`' `\pgfpointdiff` for the `veclen` function:

   ```
   \tikzset{
     arrow between''/.style args={#1 and #2}{%
       shape=single arrow, draw,
       at={(#1.north east)}, anchor=tail,
       shape border uses incircle,
       /utils/exec=%
         \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints
           {\pgfpointanchor{#1}{north east}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{south west}}%
         \pgfkeyssetevalue{/pgf/shape border rotate}{\pgfmathresult}%
         \pgfmathveclen@{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}%
         \pgfkeyssetevalue{/pgf/minimum height}{\pgfmathresult pt}}}
   ```

Of course, all solutions need some work to detect the needed anchors. (Is `#2` lower or highter than `#1`? Right or left of? What anchors should be used when they're (almost) vertically or horizontally aligned?)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.arrows, calc, math}
% 1. math library that allows 'calc'ulations:
\tikzset{
  arrow between/.style args={#1 and #2}{
    evaluate={
      coordinate \diffPoint;
      \diffPoint=(#2.south west)-(#1.north east);},
    shape=single arrow, draw,
    at={(#1.north east)}, anchor=tail,
    shape border uses incircle,
    minimum height=veclen(\diffPoint)*1pt,
    shape border rotate={atan2(\diffPointy,\diffPointx)}}}
% 2. using the original let syntax
\makeatletter
\tikzset{parse let/.code={\def\tikz@cc@stop@let in{}\tikz@let@command et #1in}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  arrow between'/.style args={#1 and #2}{
    parse let={\p{diffPoint}=($(#2.south west)-(#1.north east)$)},
    shape=single arrow, draw,
    at={(#1.north east)}, anchor=tail,
    shape border uses incircle,
    minimum height=veclen(\p{diffPoint})*1pt,
    shape border rotate={atan2(\y{diffPoint},\x{diffPoint})}}}
% 3. using lower level PGF commands
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  arrow between''/.style args={#1 and #2}{%
    shape=single arrow, draw,
    at={(#1.north east)}, anchor=tail,
    shape border uses incircle,
    /utils/exec=%
      \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints
        {\pgfpointanchor{#1}{north east}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{south west}}%
      \pgfkeyssetevalue{/pgf/shape border rotate}{\pgfmathresult}%
      \pgfmathveclen@{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}%
      \pgfkeyssetevalue{/pgf/minimum height}{\pgfmathresult pt}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (a) {A};
\node[draw, above right=2cm and 1cm of a] (b) {B};
\node[arrow between=a and b] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (a) {A};
\node[draw, above right=2cm and 1cm of a] (b) {B};
\node[arrow between'=a and b] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (a) {A};
\node[draw, above right=2cm and 1cm of a] (b) {B};
\node[arrow between''=a and b] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's also a solution to use a `to path`, i.e. `\draw(a)to[arrow between](b);` where `arrow between` uses `\tikztostart` and `\tikztotarget` do all its calculations and instead of defining an actual path, just places the node following the same calculations.

Comment: Defining `parse let/.style={insert path={let#1in}}` will possibly work, too, but why start the full parser when all we need is `let … in`?

Answer (score 3):

It is what you are looking for ?

**To answer the remark** the node is not inside the node, as one can put text in it :
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.arrows, calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{/tikz/.cd,
    my arrow/.code args={#1 and #2}{%
        \path (#1.north east) let \p1=($(#2.south west)-(#1.north east)$) in
            node[single arrow, draw, 
            minimum height={veclen(\x1,\y1)}, 
%               shape border uses incircle,
%               shape border 
            rotate={atan2(\y1,\x1)},
            anchor=tail] at (#1.north east) {\MyAwTxt};
    },
    my arrow text/.store in=\MyAwTxt,
    my arrow text=,
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (a) {A};
\node[draw, above right=2cm and 1cm of a] (b) {B};
\node[my arrow text=bob,my arrow={a and b}]{x};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Was first try**

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.arrows, calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{/tikz/.cd,
    my arrow/.code args={#1 and #2}{%
        \path (#1.north east) let \p1=($(#2.south west)-(#1.north east)$) in
            node[single arrow, draw, 
            minimum height={veclen(\x1,\y1)}, 
            shape border uses incircle,
            shape border rotate={atan2(\y1,\x1)},
            anchor=tail] at (#1.north east) {};
    },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (a) {A};
\node[draw, above right=2cm and 1cm of a] (b) {B};

%\node[my arrow={a and b}] {}; % <- OP's request

\path[my arrow={a and b}] ; % <- My first idea

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But this way you insert a node inside another one, is this formally correct?

Comment: Certainly not ;-) See my edit.

Comment: I don't thing that code args nor style args can be used with the syntax you want : `arrow between a and b`.

Comment: If you're doing `\path[my arrow];` you could just do `insert path=(#1.north east) let … in node … {}`. There's no need to start a `\path` inside another `\path`. Or you keep the definition of `my arrow` and just do `\tikzset{my arrow=a and b}`.

Answer (score 3):

Probably I am missing something, but you could do something along the lines of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314968/121799). **UPDATE** @Tarass told me that the text should be inside the arrow, which is trivially accomplishable. If I knew all the requirements, I'd be happy to implement them.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.arrows, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
  my arrow/.style n args={2}{at={($(#1)!0.5!(#2)$)},
    append after command={
      \pgfextra{\path (#1.north east) let \p1=($(#2.south west)-(#1.north east)$) in
    node[single arrow, draw, 
        minimum height={veclen(\x1,\y1)}, 
        shape border uses incircle,
        shape border rotate={atan2(\y1,\x1)},
        anchor=tail] at (a.north east) {};
    }}
  }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (a) {A};
\node[draw, above right=2cm and 1cm of a] (b) {B};
\node[my arrow={a}{b}]{C};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Tarass I thought the challenge was to put this into a node command. Does your answer do that?

Comment: Yes it works directly. As Ignasi made a remark a bout the legality of using "a node inside a node" I wrote back my first idea. But finally I don't think that the node is "inside" as both nodes are empty : {}.

Comment: I made an edit using node syntax and filling both nodes.

Comment: @Tarass I already upvoted your post before that...

Comment: So am I ;-) we are even !

Comment: @Tarass Fine. I didn't now that the position of the text is a requirement and it will be easy to slope it if that's required.

Comment: It didn't and slope doesn't work for me, I had to rotate it with the arrow commenting two no effect options.

Comment: @Tarass Sorry, there is the usual language barrier. I have no idea what "it didn't" means, but it is not too important since Ignasi seems to look for something else.

Comment: Sorry. It wasn't a requirement.