# TikZ node width depending on two nodes distance

Tags: beamer, tikz-path, tikz-calc

I am trying to make a schematic, where I need to have a rectangle with the `minimum width` set to the distance between two other rectangle nodes.
I tried to follow the solutions from [Compute the x distance between two nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63831/compute-the-x-distance-between-two-nodes) post, but in that case I always end up with the following error

> Illegal parameter number in definition of \iterate. \end{frame}

I guess I forgot something, but cannot figure out what.

Here is what I am trying to do:

[image: Schematics]

My problem is to get the green and red rectangles width.
Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, 14pt, notes]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, fit, graphs, math, positioning, shapes, shadows, tikzmark}

\begin{frame}[t]
  \frametitle{My frame}
  \framesubtitle{Example}

  \newcommand\setxveclength[5]{% newmacro, node1, anchor1, node2, anchor2
    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{#3}}{\pgfpointanchor{#4}{#5}}
    \edef#1{\the\pgf@x}
  }

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.30cm, minimum height=2.50cm, rounded corners=0.10cm, draw=gray4, fill=gray5, text=white, font=\tiny]              (PartA)      at ({$(current page.west)!0.25!(current page.east)$} |- {$(current page.north)!0.50!(current page.south)$}) {\rotatebox{270}{AAA}};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.30cm, minimum height=2.50cm, rounded corners=0.10cm, draw=gray4, fill=gray5, text=white, font=\tiny, anchor=west] (PartB)      at ([xshift=0.50mm]PartA.east) {\rotatebox{270}{BBB}};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.30cm, minimum height=2.50cm, rounded corners=0.10cm, draw=gray4, fill=gray5, text=white, font=\tiny, anchor=west] (PartC)      at ([xshift=0.50mm]PartB.east) {\rotatebox{270}{CCC}};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.30cm, minimum height=1.66cm, rounded corners=0.10cm, draw=gray4, fill=gray5, text=white, font=\tiny, anchor=south west] (PartD)at ([xshift=0.50mm]PartC.south east) {\rotatebox{270}{DDD}};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.30cm, minimum height=1.66cm, rounded corners=0.10cm, draw=gray4, fill=gray5, text=white, font=\tiny, anchor=west] (PartE)      at ([xshift=0.50mm]PartD.east) {\rotatebox{270}{EEE}};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.30cm, minimum height=1.66cm, rounded corners=0.10cm, draw=gray4, fill=gray5, text=white, font=\tiny, anchor=west] (PartF)      at ([xshift=0.50mm]PartE.east) {\rotatebox{270}{FFF}};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.30cm, minimum height=2.50cm, rounded corners=0.10cm, draw=gray4, fill=gray5, text=white, font=\tiny, anchor=south west] (PartG)at ([xshift=0.50mm]PartF.south east) {\rotatebox{270}{GGG}};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.30cm, minimum height=2.50cm, rounded corners=0.10cm, draw=gray4, fill=gray5, text=white, font=\tiny, anchor=west] (PartH)      at ([xshift=0.50mm]PartG.east) {\rotatebox{270}{HHH}};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.30cm, minimum height=2.50cm, rounded corners=0.10cm, draw=gray4, fill=gray5, text=white, font=\tiny, anchor=west] (PartI)      at ([xshift=0.50mm]PartH.east) {\rotatebox{270}{III}};

    \setxveclength{\mydist}{LinuxComp_Tel}{west}{ActiaSoft_GNSS}{east}
    \node[inner sep=0pt, minimum width=\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{PartD}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{PartF}{east}}, minimum height=0.30cm, rounded corners=0.10cm, draw=gray4, fill=GreenActia, text=white, font=\tiny, anchor=south west]  (PartJ)    at ([yshift=0.50mm]PartD.north west) {JJJ};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

I notice that the problem appears as soon as I declare the \newcommand. I do not need to invoke it

I found this solution creating the node the following way:

```
\path let \p1=($(PartD.west)-(PartF.east)$), \n1 = {veclen(\p1)}
  in node[inner sep=0pt, minimum width=\n1, minimum height=0.30cm, rounded corners=0.10cm, draw=gray4, fill=green4, text=white, font=\tiny, anchor=south west, name=PartJJJ]  at ([yshift=0.50mm]PartD.north west) {JJJ};
```

But in that case I cannot reuse the distance for a second node, that would mean that I have to recalculate the width each time, and make sure the node taken for the calculation are accurate for each rectangle with this particular width.

Thanks for the help,

Comment: Your MWE won't compile for me. Are you maybe missing some packages or definitions?

Comment: That is the reason of my postm the fact that I have the compilation error. The only additional package that might be needed if ninecolors, but I check and did not load it excplicitelly.

Comment: Thanks for pinting to the `ninecolors` package. I added this to my answer. Sorry, I first thought that your main question was about how to get this distances into the `minimum width` option, so I did not care about the `beamer` context

Comment: Related: [Q679745](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/679745)

Comment: Your command won't work because it uses a control sequence with an `@` in its name without using [`\makeatletter`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351).

Comment: Your error message comes from using `#…` inside a frame, it will need the option `fragile` to work (or you move the definition of `\setxveclength` in the preamble where it belongs).

Comment: Thanks @Qrrbrbirlbel, that was it. I put the `newcommand` in the preamble, and it started to work.  As for the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` I tried it, but since it was not in the preamble I still got the error. Of course, in the preamble, I had to add it too for the whole thing to work. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the instances I've made the `ext.positioning-plus` library of my [`tikz-ext` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext) for.

It combines the keys from `positioning` library with the syntax and measuring of the `fit` library while actually setting `minimum width` and not `text width` which is helpful if you actually want to typeset text inside that node without having to use a label. But this also means that the node will grow if you put more text in it than it will fit.

With it, you can say `below = of -(A)(B)` which will place a node `below` of the bounding box around `A` and `B` *and* sets the `minimum width` so that it will be as wide as `A` and `B` (i.e. said bounding box).

It will actually subtract twice the `outer xsep` of `minimum width` because that is included in the measurement of `A` and `B`, too. (This won't work so nicely with shapes like `circle` that ignore different values for `outer xsep` and `outer ysep` but setting different widths and heights for a circle won't work good to begin with.)

---

The `ext.positioning-plus` library also defines a positioning key `south right`, i.e.

```
\node[south right=of CCC] (DDD) {DDD};
```

which works like `right = of CCC` but uses the `south east` anchor on the reference of `CCC` and the `anchor = south west` on the `DDD` node – i.e. bottom-aligning nodes placed to the right – but since I'm opting to rotate the nodes here (instead of `\rotatebox`) I'm going to use the custom `west right` key instead.

### Code

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, 14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz, ninecolors}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.positioning-plus, chains}
\tikzset{west right/.style={right=#1.south west, anchor=north west}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{My frame}
\framesubtitle{Example}
\centering % maybe
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  start chain=going west right,
  node distance=.5mm,
  my node/.style={
    inner sep=+0pt, minimum height=+.3cm, rounded corners=+.1cm,
    draw=gray4, fill=gray5, text=white, font=\tiny},
  every on chain/.append style={my node, rotate=90},
  greenish/.style={draw=green4, fill=green5},
  redish/.style={draw=red4, fill=red5}]
\foreach \WIDTH/\NODES in {2.5cm /{AAA, BBB, CCC},
                           1.66cm/{DDD, EEE, FFF},
                           2.5cm /{GGG, HHH, III}}
  \foreach \NODE in \NODES
    \node[on chain, minimum width=\WIDTH]{\NODE};
\node[below=of -(chain-begin)(chain-end), my node, greenish] {MMM};
\node[above=of -(chain-begin)(chain-end), my node, greenish] {LLL};

\node[above=of -(chain-4)(chain-6), my node, redish] (JJJ) {JJJ};
\node[above=of -(JJJ), ultra thick, my node, redish]       {KKK};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can use a `fit` node. The `fit` option just fixes node dimensions but you can place it wherever your need. It's not necessary to envolve the reference coordinates or nodes.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, 14pt, notes]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ninecolors}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, fit, graphs, math, positioning, shapes, shadows, tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
  \frametitle{My frame}
  \framesubtitle{Example}

%  \newcommand\setxveclength[5]{% newmacro, node1, anchor1, node2, anchor2
%    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{#3}}{\pgfpointanchor{#4}{#5}}
%    \edef#1{\the\pgf@x}
%  }

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.30cm, minimum height=2.50cm, rounded corners=0.10cm, draw=gray4, fill=gray5, text=white, font=\tiny]              (PartA)      at ({$(current page.west)!0.25!(current page.east)$} |- {$(current page.north)!0.50!(current page.south)$}) {\rotatebox{270}{AAA}};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.30cm, minimum height=2.50cm, rounded corners=0.10cm, draw=gray4, fill=gray5, text=white, font=\tiny, anchor=west] (PartB)      at ([xshift=0.50mm]PartA.east) {\rotatebox{270}{BBB}};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.30cm, minimum height=2.50cm, rounded corners=0.10cm, draw=gray4, fill=gray5, text=white, font=\tiny, anchor=west] (PartC)      at ([xshift=0.50mm]PartB.east) {\rotatebox{270}{CCC}};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.30cm, minimum height=1.66cm, rounded corners=0.10cm, draw=gray4, fill=gray5, text=white, font=\tiny, anchor=south west] (PartD)at ([xshift=0.50mm]PartC.south east) {\rotatebox{270}{DDD}};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.30cm, minimum height=1.66cm, rounded corners=0.10cm, draw=gray4, fill=gray5, text=white, font=\tiny, anchor=west] (PartE)      at ([xshift=0.50mm]PartD.east) {\rotatebox{270}{EEE}};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.30cm, minimum height=1.66cm, rounded corners=0.10cm, draw=gray4, fill=gray5, text=white, font=\tiny, anchor=west] (PartF)      at ([xshift=0.50mm]PartE.east) {\rotatebox{270}{FFF}};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.30cm, minimum height=2.50cm, rounded corners=0.10cm, draw=gray4, fill=gray5, text=white, font=\tiny, anchor=south west] (PartG)at ([xshift=0.50mm]PartF.south east) {\rotatebox{270}{GGG}};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.30cm, minimum height=2.50cm, rounded corners=0.10cm, draw=gray4, fill=gray5, text=white, font=\tiny, anchor=west] (PartH)      at ([xshift=0.50mm]PartG.east) {\rotatebox{270}{HHH}};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.30cm, minimum height=2.50cm, rounded corners=0.10cm, draw=gray4, fill=gray5, text=white, font=\tiny, anchor=west] (PartI)      at ([xshift=0.50mm]PartH.east) {\rotatebox{270}{III}};

    \node[fit={(PartD.west) (PartF.east)}, inner sep=0pt, minimum height=.3cm, rounded corners=.1cm, draw=gray4,fill=red!70!black, text=white, font=\tiny, anchor=south west, label={[font=\tiny,text=white]center:JJJ}] (PartJ) at ([yshift=0.5mm]PartD.north west){};

    \node[fit={(PartD.west) (PartF.east)}, inner sep=0pt, minimum height=.3cm, rounded corners=.1cm, draw=gray4,fill=red!70!black, text=white, font=\tiny, anchor=south west, label={[font=\tiny,text=white]center:KKK}] (PartK) at ([yshift=0.5mm]PartJ.north west){};

    \node[fit={(PartA.west) (PartI.east)}, inner sep=0pt, minimum height=.3cm, rounded corners=.1cm, draw=gray4,fill=green!70!black, anchor=south west, label={[font=\tiny,text=white]center:LLL}] (PartL) at ([yshift=0.5mm]PartA.north west){};

    \node[fit={(PartA.west) (PartI.east)}, inner sep=0pt, minimum height=.3cm, rounded corners=.1cm, draw=gray4,fill=green!70!black, anchor=north west, label={[font=\tiny,text=white]center:MMM}] (PartM) at ([yshift=-0.5mm]PartA.south west){};
    
%    \setxveclength{\mydist}{LinuxComp_Tel}{west}{ActiaSoft_GNSS}{east}
%    \node[inner sep=0pt, minimum width=\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{PartD}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{PartF}{east}}, minimum height=0.30cm, rounded corners=0.10cm, draw=gray4, fill=GreenActia, text=white, font=\tiny, anchor=south west]  (PartJ)    at ([yshift=0.50mm]PartD.north west) {JJJ};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the solution provided by [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63769/47927). And you can use loops and styles to simplify your code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{ninecolors}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

    \makeatletter
    \tikzset{
        span nodes horizontally/.style 2 args={
            insert path={
                \pgfextra{
                    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{east}}
                    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
                }
            },
            minimum width={\pgf@xa-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}
        },
        span nodes vertically/.style 2 args={
            insert path={
                \pgfextra{
                    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{south}}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{north}}
                    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
                }
            },
            minimum height={\pgf@ya-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}
        },
    }
    \makeatother

    \tikzset{
        rounded/.style={
            inner sep=0pt, 
            minimum width=0.30cm, 
            minimum height=0.30cm, 
            rounded corners=0.10cm, 
            draw=gray4,
            fill=gray5, 
            text=white, 
            font=\tiny, 
        }
    }
    \makeatother

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (Init) at ([xshift=-0.50mm]{$(current page.west)!0.25!(current page.east)$} |- {$(current page.north)!0.50!(current page.south)$});
        \foreach \h/\n/\c [remember=\n as \lastn (initially Init)] in {
            2.5/PartA/AAA,
            2.5/PartB/BBB,
            2.5/PartC/CCC,
            1.66/PartD/DDD,
            1.66/PartE/EEE,
            1.66/PartF/FFF,
            2.5/PartG/GGG,
            2.5/PartH/HHH,
            2.5/PartI/III
        } {
            \node[rounded, minimum height={\h*1cm}, anchor=south west] (\n) 
                at ([xshift=0.50mm]\lastn.south east) {\rotatebox{270}{\c}};
        }
    
        \node[rounded, span nodes horizontally={PartD}{PartF}, fill=green4, anchor=south west] (PartJJJ) 
            at ([yshift=0.50mm]PartD.north west) {JJJ};
            
        % variation for vertical span

        \node[rounded, minimum width=2em, anchor=north west] (PartK) 
            at ([yshift=-0.50mm]PartA.south west) {KKK};

        \node[rounded, minimum width=2em, anchor=north west] (PartL) 
            at ([yshift=-0.50mm]PartK.south west) {LLL};

        \node[rounded, span nodes vertically={PartK}{PartL}, fill=green4, anchor=south west] (PartM) 
            at ([xshift=0.50mm]PartL.south east) {\rotatebox{270}{MM}};
            
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Probably a better and more robust solution would be (thaks again to Qrrbrbirlbel):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{ninecolors}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

    \makeatletter
    \tikzset{
        span nodes horizontally/.code 2 args={
            \pgf@process{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{east}}}
            \pgfkeyssetevalue{/pgf/minimum width}{\the\pgf@x-2*(\noexpand\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep})}
        },
        span nodes vertically/.code 2 args={
            \pgf@process{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{south}}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{north}}}
            \pgfkeyssetevalue{/pgf/minimum height}{\the\pgf@y-2*(\noexpand\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep})}
        },
    }
    \makeatother

    \tikzset{
        rounded/.style={
            inner sep=0pt, 
            minimum width=0.30cm, 
            minimum height=0.30cm, 
            rounded corners=0.10cm, 
            draw=gray4,
            fill=gray5, 
            text=white, 
            font=\tiny, 
        }
    }
    \makeatother

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (Init) at ([xshift=-0.50mm]{$(current page.west)!0.25!(current page.east)$} |- {$(current page.north)!0.50!(current page.south)$});
        \foreach \h/\n/\c [remember=\n as \lastn (initially Init)] in {
            2.5/PartA/AAA,
            2.5/PartB/BBB,
            2.5/PartC/CCC,
            1.66/PartD/DDD,
            1.66/PartE/EEE,
            1.66/PartF/FFF,
            2.5/PartG/GGG,
            2.5/PartH/HHH,
            2.5/PartI/III
        } {
            \node[rounded, minimum height={\h*1cm}, anchor=south west] (\n) 
                at ([xshift=0.50mm]\lastn.south east) {\rotatebox{270}{\c}};
        }
    
        \node[rounded, span nodes horizontally={PartD}{PartF}, fill=green4, anchor=south west] (PartJJJ) 
            at ([yshift=0.50mm]PartD.north west) {JJJ};
            
        % variation for vertical span

        \node[rounded, minimum width=2em, anchor=north west] (PartK) 
            at ([yshift=-0.50mm]PartA.south west) {KKK};

        \node[rounded, minimum width=2em, anchor=north west] (PartL) 
            at ([yshift=-0.50mm]PartK.south west) {LLL};

        \node[rounded, span nodes vertically={PartK}{PartL}, fill=green4, anchor=south west] (PartM) 
            at ([xshift=0.50mm]PartL.south east) {\rotatebox{270}{MM}};
            
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

---

Both solutions also work inside a `beamer` context.

Comment: The solution looks nice, but unfortunetelly, I still got the "Illegal parameter number in definition of \iterate. \end{frame}" error.
I guess that this might be due to the fact that I am in a beamer environment

Comment: @Krzysztof I cannot reproduce the problem. I added an MWE that uses the `beamer` document class and it compiles fine for me. Maybe try to compile from scratch. There might be some error stuck in one of the auxiliary files that were created during one of the last compilations.

Comment: May I suggest `span nodes horizontally/.code 2 args=\pgf@process{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{east}}}\pgfkeyssetevalue{/pgf/minimum width}{\the\pgf@x-2*(\noexpand\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep})}}`. `insert path` and `\pgfextra` is a detour to executing TeX code → `.code` handler (or `/utils/exec=` in a style). `\pgf@process` to be on the safe side in case `\pgfpointdiff` overwrites some values like `\pgf@xa` itself (unlikely but still). When `minimum width` will be evaluated `\pgf@xa` might already be another value → better expand it then and there.

Comment: Check your `JJJ` node, it is a tad wider than its reference because of their `outer sep`s.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel True! I need to wrap my head around this first ... Actually, I first thought to go with `.code` but I did not get how to correctly set a key value in this context. Thanks, now I know!

Comment: You can always use `\pgfkeysalso`, `\tikzset` or any other `\pgfkeys` macro inside your code. (A `.style` is just a `.code` that puts its argument in a `\pgfkeysalso`.)