# single arrow shape not match start and point exactly

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish start/end of the arrow match the point A/B exactly.

```
\documentclass[convert,border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows, calc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getxy}[3]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\darr}[3]{%
  \getxy{(#1)}{\ax}{\ay}
  \getxy{(#2)}{\bx}{\by}
  \newcommand{\ang}{atan((\by-\ay)/(\bx-\ax))}
  \path (#1) -- (#2) node[
    draw=black,single arrow,midway,inner sep=0mm,outer sep=0mm,
    insert path={let \p1=($(#1)-(#2)$) in},     
    minimum width=0mm,
    minimum height={veclen(\x1,\y1)},
    single arrow head extend=2mm,
    double arrow head extend=2mm,
    rotate=\ang,
  ] {#3};
 }%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (3,3);
  \darr{A}{B}{hello}
  \draw[red!90] (A) grid (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `center` anchor isn't in the true center of the node but at the center of the rectangular text bit.

You will have to use the `tail` anchor and `at start` if I'm understanding you correctly.
That said, you don't even need the `rotate` part if you use `sloped`.

You can also do use `rotate` but without the actual path in the first place: [Can we use `let` (from `TikZ`) inside a node's style definition?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/419991)

### Code

```
\documentclass[convert,border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows, calc}
\newcommand{\darr}[3]{%
  \path (#1) -- (#2) node[
    shape=single arrow, draw=black,
    at start, anchor=tail,
    inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm,
    insert path={let \p1=($(#2)-(#1)$) in},
    minimum width=0mm,
    minimum height={veclen(\x1,\y1)},
    single arrow head extend=2mm,
    double arrow head extend=2mm,
%    rotate={atan2(\y1,\x1)}
  ] {#3};}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (3,3);
  \darr{A}{B}{hello}
  \draw[red!90] (A) grid (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]