# Trapezium size issues Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-shape, tikz-node

I have a code that generates a flow chart. It's not entirely complete, it just needs arrows which is besides everything. This issue I have is the process nodes, trapeziums, aren't the same size even though I pre defined them.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzstyle{startstop} =   [rectangle, text centered, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{io} =          [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=-70,text centered,text width = 2cm,minimum height=1cm, minimum width=2cm, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} =     [rectangle, text centered, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} =    [diamond, text badly centered, text width=4.5em, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} =       [thick,->,>=stealth]

% Does Node distance by sides instead of centers.
\tikzstyle{my below of} = [below=of #1.south]
\tikzstyle{my right of} = [right=of #1.east]
\tikzstyle{my left of} = [left=of #1.west]
\tikzstyle{my above of} = [above=of #1.north]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DOCUMENT INFO
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.1cm,auto]
\node (Start) [startstop] {Program Startup};
\node (UsrStat) [decision, my below of=Start] {New or Returning User?};
\node (CrtUsr) [process, my right of=UsrStat] {Create User};
\node (LogCred) [io, my below of=UsrStat] {Login Credentials};
\node (ValCred) [process, my below of=LogCred] {Validate Credentials};
\node (ValRes) [decision, my below of=ValCred] {Valid or Invalid Credentials?};
\node (Login) [process, my below of=ValRes] {Login};
\node (ConUI) [process, my below of=Login] {Contact UI};
\node (Com) [io, my below of=ConUI, text width = 2.1cm] {Command};
\node (ExDec) [decision, my below of=Com] {Exit Command?};
\node (ComPros) [process, my right of=Com] {Command Process};
\node (Exit) [startstop, my below of=ExDec] {Exit Program};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But when I run it, I get the following[image: Command is bigger then Login Credentials] I have played with changing the text width, minimum height and width and cant seem to get it right. I would like them to have a minimum width of 2cm as the others.

Comment: @pschulz In the provided MWE, replace `Command` by `Command\\\null` and you will see the problem...

Comment: Related : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106969/drawing-parallelogram-with-fixed-angle-width-and-height

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the first sight this looks as bug, however reading documentation an link provided in *percusse* comment show, that in such a cases the option `trapezium stretches=true` should be added to node style definition:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, shapes.geometric, }

\tikzset{flowchart/.style = {
     base/.style = {draw=black, 
                    inner sep=1mm, outer sep=0mm,
                    text width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,
                    align=flush center},
startstop/.style = {base, fill=red!30},
  process/.style = {base, fill=orange!30},
 decision/.style = {base, diamond, aspect=1.2, fill=green!30},
       io/.style = {base, trapezium,
                    trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=-70,
                    trapezium stretches=true, %%%% <-- added
                    fill=blue!30},
     arrow/.style = {thick, -stealth}
                    }}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[flowchart,
    node distance=0.5cm, auto
                    ]
\node (n1) [io] {Login Credentials};
\node (n2) [io, below=of n1]        {Command};
\node (n3) [io, below=of n2]        {Command Command Command};
\node (n4) [process, below=of n3]   {Validate Credentials};
%
\draw[dashed]
    (n4.north west) -- ++ (0,5)
    (n4.north east) -- ++ (0,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

*Off-topic:* 
above MWE has in comparison to your MWE the following changes:

- instead `\tikzstyle`, which is considered obsolete the `\tikzset` is used
- `\tikzset`, containing definitions of nodes used in flowcharts is named "flowchart" (if you not liked this, just erase this part of `\tikzset`). Consequently the `tikzpicture`s with flowchart, had to call this settings with its name (see MWE above)
- in positioning is (directly) used syntax determined in `positioning` library
- defined is common `base` style, which is then used in all other node's styles

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to Tikz and I found the layout I posted on a ShareLatex forum for flowcharts.